# background image css

Tags: css

newbie question but i can't figure it out:

How to make the background image covers the whole page but no repeat?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.

```
body{
  background-image:url(path to image) no-repeat left top
}
```

Your image should be large enough because you are not repeating it.

Comment: adding  "no-repeat lef top " the image is now not even showing

Comment: sorry didn't realise i was using background-image.. Now how do stretch the image to cover the whole page?

Comment: @ranald-yoh: Have a look at this please: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
body { background:url(/file.jpg) no-repeat top center; }
```

If it looks off you probably need more heightness.

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

Comment: adding  "no-repeat top center" the image is now not even showing

Comment: sorry didn't realise i was using background-image.. Now how do stretch the image to cover the whole page?